# Chrome File Browser - access full path

Tags: angular, html, google-chrome, go

I understand that due to security reasons a browser doesn't allow me to access the full path of a file when selected via FileBrowser in a file input field.

Still, I am facing a problem where this feature is needed. Maybe someone can provide an alternative solution where I don't have to reinvent any wheels.

The situation is as follows.

- The backend and the operating user have both access to the same filesystem.
- The user has to pick one or multiple file location/s and inform the backend.
- The backend will then schedule a task.
- Meanwhile the file contents may be altered by the user but the location will remain the same.
- The users browser is under our control. So we could use extensions if needed.

Questions

- Is there any Chrome option that would circumvent the security barrier and allow me to access the full path?
- Is there any helpful Chrome extension out there?
- Is there any known alternative solution or "best practice" advise to this problem?

Comment: To answer your questions: No. No. Yes: Have the backend display a list of files read from the FS so that the backend knows the full path. Let the user select via checkbox or via clicking a link instead of a input type=file element.

Comment: That is also my conclusion so far. We already prototyped a similar solution to your suggestion. But hoped for another solution where we could reuse a system file browser which the user is familiar with. Further listing files on backend adds the burden of permission handling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you'd want to be reusing either `<input type="file">` or *how* you'd use the system filebrowser to be able to do this.

Your problem statement would be much easier to solve if you simply listed the files available in a directory, and then performed an action based on that information.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    r := http.NewServeMux()

    r.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(".")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        out := "<ul>"
        for _, f := range files {
            v := url.Values{}
            v.Add("file", f.Name())
            out += fmt.Sprintf(`<li><a href="/do?%s">%s</a></li>`, v.Encode(), f.Name())
        }
        out += "</ul>"

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
        fmt.Fprintf(w, out)
    })

    r.HandleFunc("/do", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, r.URL.Query().Get("file"))
    })

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":8080",
        Handler: r,
    }

    if err := server.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/bSgm4nAUUYg

> **Note:** This code is **not** production safe. You have to worry about people potentially accessing directories above where you are `..`, and all sorts of fun stuff that comes with sharing server information. But, it's just intended to help you get started.

Then, you don't have to worry about what the browser is passing to you, you're completely in control.

Comment: There are 2 reasons. 

First: The people are already familiar with the native file system. They easily recognise the locations when they browse.

Second: Permission control. Native file system browser would not allow a user to enter a folder that he has no permission to see. On the backend we would have to filter folders based on users permissions. Due to the current setup this is not an easy task to solve.

Comment: Both of those points are ultimately going against the grain. If the user is on the same filesystem as the server that's running it, you can always list files that only the user has permissions to by running the go process as the user, which would not be able to access something they couldn't, to implement what you're looking for. From the perspective of users are used to the native file system, they're also used to web filesystems. Look at OneDrive, Google Drive, iCloud, etc.

Comment: The backend is running inside a docker container, where the user ids and groups of each individual user are simply not present as far as i know. Different parts of the file system are mounted into that container. Also there is Kerberos involved. If you know how to list files for a user under these circumstances feel free to share as i am currently investigating that path.

The specific user group in question is not familiar with web file systems.